Http/500 Code: Unknown error
QField cannot refresh projects in QFieldCloud Projects/My Project. It shows the following message:
[http/500] https://app.qfield.cloud/api/v1/projects/Server Error. {"code": “unknown error”, “message”:”QField Cloud unknown error}
I tried to uninstall, install again, change the network it is connected to.
For my colleagues it functions.
